# My Fibonacci algorithm code says, that index out of range, and I cannot understand, why

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, algorithm, fibonacci

Here is my code for counting Fibonacci number, and when I compile it, here is an error "Index out of range".

```
func fib(n: Int) -> Int { 
    var fibArray = [Int]()
    fibArray.insert(0, at: 0)
    fibArray.insert(1, at: 1)
    for i in 2...n {
        fibArray[i] = fibArray[i-1] + fibArray[i-2]
    }
    return fibArray[n]
}
var a = fib(n: 8)
print(a)
```

Comment: Which line causes the crash? > What' `fibArray` value at that moment? Could you print intermediary values of `fibArray`, and check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were doing nicely with items 0 and 1, so might as well keep the same logic in your loop.

```
    fibArray.insert(fibArray[i-1] + fibArray[i-2], at: i)
```